# Change XML Attribute By bat file

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file

I have the following XML File:

```
<MyXML myatt="true">
   <MyElement>Test</MyElement>
</MyXML>
```

I want to change the attirbute `myatt` by .bat file
How can i do it with PowerShell?
Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried and explain what you mean by "change `myatt`" do you want to change the name or change the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the solution but i dont think its the best solution

```
<# : batch portion
@echo off
setlocal

set "xmlfile=test.xml"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell #>

[xml]$xml = gc $env:xmlfile
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes('MyXML')
foreach($node in $nodes)
{
     node.SetAttribute('myatt','false')
}
$xml.Save($env:xmlfile)
```

Comment: This code looks (mostly) familiar.... And yes, parsing XML as structured markup is absolutely correct. Scraping and hacking XML as predictably formatted flat text is easily broken if the formatting changes.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35534146.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "tag=%1"
SET "attribute=%2"
SET "value=%~3"
IF NOT DEFINED value ECHO(Required tag, attribute, "value"&GOTO :EOF 

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=<=> " %%c IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "changed="
  IF /i "%%c"=="%tag%" IF "%%d"=="%attribute%" SET "changed=y"&ECHO(^<%%c %attribute%="%value%"^>
  IF NOT DEFINED changed ECHO(%%a
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35534146.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

It is not important that the filenames I used were `.txt`, replace with `.xml` as required.

Note that this merely replaces any line beginning

> *delimiters*tag*delimiters*attribute*delimiters*anything

with

`<tag attribute="value">`

Run as

> *thisbatch* tag attribute "value required"

where the quotes are only required if the value contains separators like spaces.